# Add Click Event with ExtJS Panel

Tags: extjs

I am trying to create panel in ext js and got success on that but I also want to add click event with this

```
       {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            x: 10,
            y: parseInt(panelCreation[i - 1].y) + 
               parseInt(panelCreation[i -1].height) + 10,
            width: twidth,
            height: theight,
            layout: 'absolute'                
        }
```

I don't want to add click event separately I want to add with this code like after layout:absolute add comma and event please help me in this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add in the following for a click event:

```
listeners: {
   'render': function(panel) {
       panel.body.on('click', function() {
           alert('onclick');
       });
    }
}
```

EDIT: to get the X and Y coordinates of the click event you can change the click event handler as follows...

```
panel.body.on('click', function(e) {
   alert('X: ' + e.getPageX());
   alert('Y: ' + e.getPageY());
});
```

Comment: I already found that but anyway Thanks Kirk Woll for your response thats working fine.

Comment: @Jaitsu, don't want to post another question, but how can i get click coordinates if this event?

Comment: @JamesHalsall In MVC ExtJS4, this seems to make it so that the panel's body's click event is triggered from other views as well that don't have this controller. Do you have the same issue ?

Comment: I haven't used ExtJS 4, so I can't help you there unfortunately

Comment: If you want the event to fire on header and panels like lbar clicks, use  `panel.el.on('click', function(){...})` instead of `panel.body.on('click', function(){...})`

Answer (score 3):

```
new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'The Clickable Panel',
    listeners: {
        render: function(p) {
            // Append the Panel to the click handler's argument list.
            p.getEl().on('click', handlePanelClick.createDelegate(null, [p], true));
        },
        single: true  // Remove the listener after first invocation
    }
});
```

Comment: Friends can you please post the codes for clickable line chart.

Comment: I find this answer better than the accepted one because it also fires the event when the click is performed at the header.

Answer (score 3):

There's, in my opinion, a much more straightforward way to do this...(taken straight out of the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-listeners)). For more info about adding a listener see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener). (Ext Js 4)

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar'
    }],
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
            fn: function(){ console.log('click el'); }
        },
        dblclick: {
            element: 'body', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
            fn: function(){ console.log('dblclick body'); }
        }
    }
});
```